# How do you skip a <td> tag in HTML

Tags: html, charts, internet-explorer-10

I want to know how do you skip a  tag in HTML5.0. I mean **literally**, without CSS. Instead of an empty  box, I want it to be filled in, not just blank. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Skip in what sense? HTML does not process anything, so how would it skip? And how do you fill something that you have skipped? Describe what you actually want and demonstrate it with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use colspan or rowspan.

```
            <table>
            <tr>

                <td colspan="2">
                    Header
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   Text
                </td>
               <td>
                   Text
               </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   Text
                </td>
                <td>
                   Text
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>
```